# smooth affine algebraic curves and their subschemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, dedekind-domain

I am reading a lot about curves at the moment and I am a little confused:
Let $X= Spec K[X]$ denote a smooth affine algebraic curve. Then, according to some sources, the ring $K[X]$ is a Dedekind domain. But this would mean $X$ to constist of only two points, the generic point and a special point...is this correct?? How can the curve constist of only two points??

Also, considering a subscheme $Y \hookrightarrow X$, is the coordinate ring of $Y$ again a Dedekind domain (is $Y$ a curve?). The only way $Y$ could be a nontrivial subscheme would be for $K[Y]$ to be a field, consisting of only one prime ideal $(0)$.

Am I mistaken at some point here?

Comment: I don't know how you conclude that $X$ consists of only two points.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little bit confused!

But I expose an easy example: let $X=\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}$ be the affine line over an integrally closed field $\mathbb{K}$, then $X$ as affine scheme is $Spec\mathbb{K}[t]=\{(t-a)\,\text{prime ideal of}\,\mathbb{K}[t]:a\in\mathbb{K}\}\cup\{(0)\}$; by hypothesis, $\mathbb{K}$ has infinitely many elements, and $\mathbb{K}[x]$ is a Dedekind domain!, indeed: $\mathbb{K}[x]$ is integrally closed and Noetherian ring, and its Krull dimension is $1$.

If you take a closed point $y$ of $X$, you find that $\{y\}=Spec\mathbb{K}[t]_{\displaystyle/\mathfrak{m}_y}\cong Spec\mathbb{K}=\{(0)\}$ the zero ideal of $\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you too and thank you for your answer! But if the coordinate ring of the scheme is a Dedekind domain, doesn't this mean that the spectrum (being a spectrum of a discrete valuation ring) consists of two points? I am surely misunderstanding something, but I cannot identify my mistake here.

Comment: No; warning: all Discrete Valuation Rings (DVR) are Dedekind ring but not vice versa! Furthermore, the DVR's are local rings, when the coordinate rings of the affine varieties can be not local rings; as in the previous example. If you take the local ring $\mathbb{Z}[t]_{(t,2)}$, the its spectrum has more of two points because the its Krull dimension is $2$.

Comment: Thank you! It all makes sense now :)

Comment: Not at all, @arla! It's a pleasure. ;)